# How to detect how many GeoCode requests per day I'm making?

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoder

I understand that the Google Geocoding API has a limit of 2,500 requests per day.

Is there a way that I could detect the amount of requests that I am making?

Answer (score 0):

Just log every request you're doing...

Something like that

```
var i = 0;

if(i < 2500)
{
    // Your geocoding request here

    i++;
}
//Display i, or save it into a file
```